# Why does \fbox sometimes place the box *over* the graphic image?

Tags: graphics, positioning, boxes

If I scale the graphic by, say 2.0, I can see the graphic poking out from behind the `\fbox`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Can you give us an example (source code)?

Comment: How do I do it - as a file?

Comment: Sorry, I am generating a dvi file not a pdf. Already got the xcolor package included. This happens to ALL graphics and happened suddenly, but I cannot figure what it was that caused it.

Answer (score 5):

The default `\fbox` draws the four lines of the frame and places the content in one go. Therefore some lines are placed before and some after the content. If the content is a trimmed image then the trimmed part will be printed over the lines placed before. Also, depending on the zoom level the PDF viewer might mix up both.  You can't do much about the latter, but if you load the `xcolor` package than `\fbox` gets redefined so that the content is placed first and then the lines are drawn, so that they are always shown above it, as it is supposed to be.